# How to move MSMQ message to another queue

Tags: windows, msmq

I have a problem moving messages from one queue to another on my development box (Windows 8.1).
I'm using MassTransit service bus which generates three private queues per service instance for me. One for the normal inbound messages, one for error messages and one for subscriptions. 
When there's a fault in a message consumer MT tries a few times before it moves it to the error queue.

Now during development this happens frequently, but instead of starting the whole chain of events from the top all the time, I would like to move the messages back to the inbound queue to retry it after changing the code. So naturally I try the MSMQ snap-in found in the Control-Panel/Administrative Tools/Computer Management and under Services and Applications->Message Queuing I open the error queue in question, right-clicking a message and selects All Tasks->Move.

Here I would assume that the combobox should contain all my private queues, but no, it's empty. And trying to input it doesn't help. I only get a message that says

> Failed to move message from
>   DIRECT=OS:{computer name}\private${source_queue} to
>   DIRECT=OS:{whatever I try to write in the combobox} because the 
>   target queue or subqueue is invalid.

Please help me with the syntax, or whatever else could be wrong!

Comment: Somehow I missed or forgot that I read about the MassTransit tool named BusDriver that supports this scenario, read more about it [here](http://josephvano.wordpress.com/2012/09/11/masstransit-moving-messages-from-error-queue/). However, I still want to know how to do it in the Windows built-in UI...

Comment: You can't. Once a message is delivered, that's the end of the line for it. You can only read the message, take it's contents and create a new message from it which you send to the new queue. If you see a 3rd party application that does message moves, that should be what it's doing under the covers. Moving messages can cause problems for acknowledgements and journaling (if used) as the original message is read which can trigger ACKs, reset timers, etc. Moving messages in the UI (AFAIK) is to move messages within a queue between subqueues.

Answer (score 0):

I use ServiceBusExplorer which can be downloaded from https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer

Then do the following steps,

1. Connect using your connection string
2. Select your **_error** queue and press the **messages** button
3. Highlight the messages that you want to re-queue
4. Right click and choose to **Resubmit in batch mode**

[image]

5. Choose **submit** and then your queue you consume from (the one that they came on through originally)

Answer (score -1):

The easiest solution is to use a tool to move messages, like [MSMQ Studio](https://msmq-studio.com).

Comment: Explaining how to use this tool would make this a better answer. Use the EDIT button to add usage information to help out the person asking the question.